# How to allow the access automatically to the webcam

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

I am trying to develop a web page that access to my webcam using the following JS code:

```
(function( $ ){

$.fn.html5_qrcode = function(qrcodeSuccess, qrcodeError, videoError) {
'use strict';

var height = this.height();
var width = this.width();

if (height == null) {
  height = 250;
}

if (width == null) {
  width = 300;
}

var vidTag = '<video id="html5_qrcode_video" width="' + width + 'px" height="' +   height   + 'px"></video>' 
var canvasTag = '<canvas id="qr-canvas" width="' + (width - 2) + 'px" height="' + (height - 2) + 'px" style="display:none;"></canvas>' 

this.append(vidTag);
this.append(canvasTag);



var video = $('#html5_qrcode_video').get(0);
var canvas;
var context; 
var localMediaStream;

$('#qr-canvas').each(function(index, element) {
  canvas = element;
  context = element.getContext('2d');   
});



var scan = function() {
  if (localMediaStream) {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 307,250);

    try {
      qrcode.decode();
    } catch(e) {
      qrcodeError(e);
    }

    setTimeout(scan, 500);

  } else {
    setTimeout(scan,500);
  }
}//end snapshot function

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;
navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||      navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

var successCallback = function(stream) {
    video.src = (window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)) || stream;
    localMediaStream = stream;

    video.play();
    setTimeout(scan,1000);
}

// Call the getUserMedia method with our callback functions
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, successCallback, videoError);
} else {
    console.log('Native web camera streaming (getUserMedia) not supported in this  browser.');
    // Display a friendly "sorry" message to the user
}

qrcode.callback = qrcodeSuccess;

}; // end of html5_qrcode
})( jQuery );
```

I run my application and it works, but before that the cam is opened, I've got the access permission window, so I wander if there is any solution that allow me to open the webcam without ask.

Comment: No. Thats not possible and be glad so

Comment: For more info, google for 'sandbox javascript'

Answer (score 1):

For obvious reasons you can not turn people webcams on and start recording without consent.

Locally you can open up for specific features without asking with some vendors like Chrome by setting up policies. I have added abit of links in the comments

Comment: @user1444393 well okay =] For most parts it is not possible, it might be possible locally with a specific vendor. See for example https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en&ref_topic=2936229 , setup in  chrome://policy , I hope it wis what you where looking for then. Sorry if I came of rude

Comment: You can find a example file here http://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chrome/policy/policy_templates.zip  it allows for presetting allowence for webcam. You need to edit   //"VideoCaptureAllowed": false and  //"VideoCaptureAllowedUrls": ["http://www.example.com/", "http://[*.]example.edu/"]

Comment: I mentionned that it will be **"My WebCam"** not poeple ones .. :D
Besides, what about developers who develop an application to scan the QR-Code, do you think that it will be practical each time I started the mobile app, I ask the users's permession?

Comment: @user1444393 there is a big difference to doing something in the browser and doing it via a native mobile app, often the native app collects permissions while being installed. But as i mentioned if you only want to set the permssion locally this can be done in Chrome =]

Comment: thank you for your response, but could you clarify me in which file should I edit?

Comment: @user1444393 sorry, it depeands on your system. It will not be something you can distribute to you users. Check the file and read the links. Or maybe make new question focused only on implementing webcam policy in chrome on OSX or etc. and what you tried